¿Cómo mostrar información adicional en resultados de Google?
He estado trabajando con el posicionamiento SEO en Google, y estoy utilizando las etiquetas HTML5 (meta tag), pero lo único que he logrado es que aparezca otro contenido que está ubicado en el sitio web fuera del contenido que coloqué en los meta tag.
En ningún momento toma las etiquetas <meta> de html5. Solo me ha tomado el título, y el contenido que omite es: descripción, precios, etc, no me toma el contenido que le asigné.
No estoy utilizando ninguna herramienta de ayuda, solo estoy utilizando directamente código abierto. Me gustaría hacerlo como la imagen a continuación:

Actualmente estoy usando estas META TAGS.
<meta name="og:title" content="NEBRIMAR RENT A CAR - REPUBLICA DOMINICANA">
<meta name="og:description" content="¿Buscas la mejor diversión para tus vacaciones? Con Excursiones Nebrimar puedes disfrutar en familia y al mejor precio en Republica Dominicana - Punta Cana.">
<meta name="description" content="¿Buscas la mejor diversión para tus vacaciones? Con Excursiones Nebrimar puedes disfrutar en familia y al mejor precio en Republica Dominicana - Punta Cana.">
<meta name="og:locale" content="es_ES">
<meta name="robots" content="max-image-preview:large">
<meta property="og:url" content="permalink">
<meta property="og:type" content="website">
<meta property="og:image" content="/sitio/es/web/asset/img/logos/logo-plano.png">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,shrink-to-fit=no">
<link type="image/png" href="/sitio/es/web/asset/img/logos/favicon.png" rel="icon">
<link href="https://www.nebrimar.com/sitio/es/web/" rel="canonical">
<link href="https://www.nebrimar.com/sitio/es/web/" shortlink="canonical">


Eso se llama metadescripción, en cuanto reabran la pregunta te agrego una respuesta

@RuslanLópez listo!

La pregunta está mal formada y le falta información importante para poder ayudarte: "He estado investigando", ¿sobre qué tema: SEO en general, OpenGraph, meta etiquetas en HTML, microdata? "tengo varias semanas y hasta meses intentando" ¿el qué? ¿qué código has intentado? ¿cómo lo muestra Google? Me imagino que has añadido meta etiquetas, pero sin saber cómo lo estás intentando, lo más seguro es que otros usuarios te sugieran lo mismo que ya has hecho (perdiendo tu tiempo y el suyo). Lee sobre [ask] y completa el [tour] para más información (y así ganarás una nueva medalla en el sitio).

Lectura necesaria: https://ogp.me/

Estoy completamente de acuerdo con @AlvaroMontoro... esta pregunta no debería haber sido reabierta en su estado actual. Que pasa, que ahora vamos a ponernos a hacerle los deberes también a quien no quiera demostrar esfuerzo alguno?? Es una pregunta súper vaga y ni siquiera parece que haya investigado nada. Se tarda un minuto en buscar en google cómo modificar las descripciones de las búsquedas... y ni eso parece que haya hecho, pues no usa ningún término correcto. Yo creía que SO tenía unos estándares a la hora de aceptar preguntas, como demostrar investigación y ser específica.

@javdromero ese es parte del problema que indicaba con mi comentario. Seguramente OP ha usado OpenGraph para esto y no le funciona... porque la información la tiene que dar usando microdata. Mirando el código de la página que pone como ejemplo, está creada en Woocomerce y usa microdata (usando el schema de Producto).

No hay meta etiqueta para precio, por eso Google no lo debe estar tomando. ¿Puedes poner las meta etiquetas que estás usando?

Hola Alvaro, ya actualice, y ahí tengo el código que estoy utilizando.

Muchas gracias, voy a editar un poco y reabrir la pregunta.

En tus meta tags ya agregaste los open graph, lo que te haría notar es que depende de tus plataformas objetivo, open graph se usa mucho en facebook, por lo que si revisas la documentación de microdatos de facebok al respecto encontrarás que te faltaron agregar las siguientes meta tags en opengraph:
<meta property="product:brand" content="Nebrimar">
<meta property="product:availability" content="in stock">
<meta property="product:price:amount" content="99">
<meta property="product:price:currency" content="USD">
<meta property="product:retailer_item_id" content="facebook_excursion_001">
<meta property="product:item_group_id" content="fb_excursion_1">

Para saber que elementos puedes agregar en tags meta de opengraph, tags meta de schema.org o en formato JSON-LD de schema.org puedes revisar la referencia de facebook, donde te indicarán cuales elementos son obligatorios de incluir.
X (antes twitter)
si deseas optimizar tus meta tags también para twitter te recomiendo leer su documentación técnica al respecto.
En el caso de ellos no te manejan el precio, pero tus meta a agregar se verían algo así:
<meta name="twitter:title" content="NEBRIMAR RENT A CAR - REPUBLICA DOMINICANA">
<meta name="twitter:description" content="¿Buscas la mejor diversión para tus vacaciones? Con Excursiones Nebrimar puedes disfrutar en familia y al mejor precio en Republica Dominicana - Punta Cana.">
<meta name="twitter:image" content=" http://www.nebrimar.com/sitio/es/web/asset/img/logos/logo-plano.png">
<meta name="twitter:card" content="summary_large_image">

Aquí puedes consultar algunos ejemplos recomendados para varios tipos de tarjeta.
Herramientas
Si deseas generar rápidamente tus meta tags puedes revisar la herramienta webcodetools.
Si deseas validar tus meta tags para twitter usa su validador.
Si deseas consultar como ve el crawler de facebook a tu sitio puedes ir aquí.
Si deseas tener una vista previa de tu metadescrición puedes consultar alguna herramienta como ésta.
Si deseas validar tus metadatos y como podrían verse en google search puedes revisar su validador de resultados enriquecidos.
Google search
Google tiene también la oportunidad de mostrar tu sitio como resultado 0 al extrar los datos estructurados de tu sitio.
Para ello deben de cumplir con ciertas características que puedes hallar en su documentación. Te recomiendo en tu cao revisar la parte de productos, para que te quede optimizado para el google bot algo así:
 <html>
  <head>
    <title>NEBRIMAR RENT A CAR - REPUBLICA DOMINICANA</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  <div>
    <div itemtype="https://schema.org/Product" itemscope>
      <meta itemprop="sku" content="excursion-12345" />
      <meta itemprop="gtin14" content="12345678901234" />
      <meta itemprop="name" content="NEBRIMAR RENT A CAR - REPUBLICA DOMINICANA" />
      <link itemprop="image" href="http://www.nebrimar.com/sitio/es/web/asset/img/logos/logo-plano.png" />
      <meta itemprop="description" content="¿Buscas la mejor diversión para tus vacaciones? Con Excursiones Nebrimar puedes disfrutar en familia y al mejor precio en Republica Dominicana - Punta Cana." />
      <div itemprop="brand" itemtype="https://schema.org/Brand" itemscope>
        <meta itemprop="name" content="NEBRIMAR" />
      </div>
      <div itemprop="offers" itemtype="https://schema.org/Offer" itemscope>
        <link itemprop="url" href="http://www.nebrimar.com/sitio/es/offer1" />
        <meta itemprop="itemCondition" content="https://schema.org/NewCondition" />
        <meta itemprop="availability" content="https://schema.org/InStock" />
        <meta itemprop="price" content="99" />
        <meta itemprop="priceCurrency" content="USD" />
        <meta itemprop="priceValidUntil" content="2024-11-20" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </body>
</html>


otras opciones
Los meta tags no son la única opción, existe una amplia gama de microformatos, particularmente si tienes tiempo te recomiendo revisar el formato json-ld.

Con las etiquetas <meta> puedes proporcionar información general sobre la página, pero no necesariamente sobre el producto que se está anunciando/vendiendo en dicha página. Incluso OpenGraph va a quedarse corto para situaciones como ésta.
Eso es una limitación en la semántica de HTML, que está pensando para estructurar y describir el documento en sí, pero no necesariamente el contenido del mismo.
Para proporcionar información adicional y que Google la muestre en sus resultados, debes incorporar microdata a tus páginas web. Con los esquemas de microdata puedes dar significado (semántica) al contenido.
Si te fijas en el código de la página que usas de ejemplo, utiliza microdata. En concreto el esquema de Producto, que permite describir el contenido de la página como un producto que está a la venta (versión limpia de cómo se ve, está minificada en el código de la página):
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
    "@context": "https:\/\/schema.org\/",
    "@type": "Product",
    "@id": "https:\/\/excursionesnebrimar.com\/producto\/la-hacienda-%f0%9f%8c%b4%f0%9f%90%8e\/#product",
    "name": "La Hacienda \ud83c\udf34\ud83d\udc0e",
    "url": "https:\/\/excursionesnebrimar.com\/producto\/la-hacienda-%f0%9f%8c%b4%f0%9f%90%8e\/",
    "description": "Vive un d\u00eda completo de aventuras en Punta Cana. Incluye boogies \ud83d\udefb, r\u00edo \ud83c\udf0a, caballos \ud83d\udc0e, telesilla \ud83d\udea1, zip line \ud83c\udfa2, salto al vac\u00edo \ud83c\udfde\ufe0f y almuerzo buffet dominicano \ud83c\udf7d\ufe0f por solo $99 por persona. \u00a1No te lo pierdas!",
    "image": "https:\/\/excursionesnebrimar.com\/wp-content\/uploads\/2024\/05\/WhatsApp-Image-2024-05-01-at-9.40.55-PM-e1714827782589.webp",
    "sku": 300,
    "offers": [
        {
            "@type": "Offer",
            "price": "99.00",
            "priceValidUntil": "2025-12-31",
            "priceSpecification": {
                "price": "99.00",
                "priceCurrency": "USD",
                "valueAddedTaxIncluded": "false"
            },
            "priceCurrency": "USD",
            "availability": "http:\/\/schema.org\/InStock",
            "url": "https:\/\/excursionesnebrimar.com\/producto\/la-hacienda-%f0%9f%8c%b4%f0%9f%90%8e\/",
            "seller": {
                "@type": "Organization",
                "name": "Excursiones Nebrimar",
                "url": "https:\/\/excursionesnebrimar.com"
            }
        }
    ]
}
<script>

Yo siempre he usado microdata inline, dentro de los propios elementos HTML, no había visto esta implementación hasta ahora. Pero aparece como una de las opciones en la propia página del esquema de Producto (mira la opción de JSON-LD en el ejemplo 3).
Obviamente, debes adaptar ese código a tu página. Te puedes guiar por las descripciones del esquema, pero básicamente:

@context y @type los dejas igual porque son los que identifican el tipo de elemento que describes (un producto)
@id es un identificador único
name es el nombre del producto
url es la página web del producto
description es la descripción del producto
image es la imagen asociada al producto
offers se usa para indicar la oferta del producto, si está disponble, su precio, fechas, etc. No necesitas todos los valores, pero para lo que quieres hacer, deberás usar al menos @id, price y priceCurrency.


Gracias, Alvaro Montoro, voy a probarlo.

@YoseiRomero cuando lo añadas a tu página web, puedes probar cómo se va a leer con este validador de Schema.org.
